# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'correctAnswer')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After long time, I am posting question in Stackoverflow. I am learning React with JS. Everything was easy but when I compile the whole project and run using npm start it never displays my website. So with the help of developers tools I come to know this error:
[image]

One helper function being used in the project is following:

```js
export const shuffleAnswers = (question) => {
  const unshuffledAnswers = [
    question.**correctAnswer**,
    ...question.incorrectAnswers,
  ];

  return unshuffledAnswers
    .map((unshuffledAnswer) => ({
      sort: Math.random(),
      value: unshuffledAnswer,
    }))
    .sort((a, b) => a.sort - b.sort)
    .map((a) => a.value);
};
```

another file, quiz.js uses the shuffleAnswers function quite few times. I doubted case "NEXT_QUESTION" but don't see any other way to use 'answers' here.

```js
import { createContext, useReducer } from "react";
import questions from "../../data";
import { normalizeQuestions, shuffleAnswers } from "../../helpers";

const initialState = {
  currentQuestionIndex: 0,
  questions:[],
  showResults: false,
  answers: shuffleAnswers(questions[0]),
  currentAnswer: "",
  correctAnswerCount: 0,
};
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  console.log("reducer", action, state);
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SELECT_ANSWER": {
      const correctAnswerCount =
        action.payload ===
        state.questions[state.currentQuestionIndex].correctAnswer
          ? state.correctAnswerCount + 1
          : state.correctAnswerCount;
      return {
        ...state,
        currentAnswer: action.payload,
        correctAnswerCount
      };
    }
    case "NEXT_QUESTION": {
      const showResults =
        state.currentQuestionIndex === state.questions.length - 1; // array index starts from 0
      const currentQuestionIndex = showResults
        ? state.currentQuestionIndex
        : state.currentQuestionIndex + 1;
      const answers = showResults
        ? []
        : shuffleAnswers(state.questions[currentQuestionIndex]);

      return {
        ...state,
        currentQuestionIndex,
        showResults,
        answers,
        currentAnswer: "",
      };
    }

    case "RESTART": {
      return initialState;
    }

    case "LOADED_QUESTIONS":{
        console.log("loaded Questions:", state, action);
        const normalizedQuestions = normalizeQuestions(action.payload)
        return {
            ...state,
            questions: normalizedQuestions,
            answers:shuffleAnswers(normalizedQuestions[0])
        }
    
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const QuizContext = createContext();

export const QuizProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const value = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  console.log(value);

  return <QuizContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</QuizContext.Provider>;
};
```

I don't understand the error I checked the code again and again couldn't find the reason for the error. ANy clue would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Check where `shuffleAnswers` is being called and make sure the value it's being passed isn't `undefined` (in this case, check `quiz.js`)

Comment: Also if you are using VSCODE, use debugger and right click on the function and click "See All references"

Comment: `answers: shuffleAnswers(questions[0])`, your `questions[0]` is `undefined`. What is in your data file that you get `questions` from (`import questions from "../../data";`) ?